# Returning post data as JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, forms, post

consider the function

```
public JsonResult poststuff()
    {
        var form = Request.Form;
        return new JsonResult() { Data = form };
    }
```

consider the submitted data (JSON)

```
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: "50"
    }
```

**This is my question**

Is there any way to return the post data as a JSON? Without having to pull the data apart and insert it into an object of an type?

I feel like i've been trawling the web for an answer but has not been able to find one ... and know i turn to you.

**The returndata would be prefered as the following:**

{
    data: {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 50
    }
}
**or even better** {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 50
}

Is it even possible to do it in a simple way? I know it is i PHP but i've never succeeded in finding an answer in C# .NET

As a reference, the wished result can be created in PHP as easy as

```
$input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
echo json_encode($input_data);
```

Comment: isn't this data the same what you posted? Why do you need it back?

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net MVC or Web API?

Comment: @Carlos487 JsonResult is specific to Mvc, isn't it?

Comment: It's just a "proof-of-concepts" i'm working on - it's meant to only return the posted data :) Ideally i would like to cast an form directly to an object.

Comment: @SteffenPrüsse Replace your method with mine. You will get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using form to post the data, then you can use the `[FormCollection][1]` class as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostStuff(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //If data is POSTed as a form
    foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
    {
        var value = formCollection[key];
        data.Add(key, value);
    }
            
    return Json(data, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here, we are just looping through the collection POSTed from the form and adding it to the dictionary. This dictionary is then passed to `JsonResult`.